# Perturbative calculation of hierarchy problem

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization, perturbation-theory, higgs, fine-tuning

I've been trying to understand the origin of the hierarchy problem for the Higgs mass but I've tied myself into some pretty nasty knots and I'm hoping someone can shed some light on this.

So as I see it the problem is that assuming $\Lambda$ is some UV cutoff for the SM (e.g. the Planck scale or just some new massive particle), the Higgs mass is of the form
$$
m_H^2 = m_0^2 - a\Lambda^2 + \ldots
$$
where $m_0$ is the bare mass and $a$ is $\mathcal{O}(1)$. Since $\Lambda^2$ is huge, $m_0$ would have to be tuned very precisely for $m_H$ to be small.

I have two problems with this, though I suppose they are connected. First, what is hiding in the $\ldots$? If I'm not mistaken, basic counting of divergences implies that the Feynman diagrams contributing to $m_H$ are at most quadratically divergent, but this in principle permits some logarithmic factors such as $\Lambda^2\log^n(\Lambda)$. Now consider the infinite series
$$
\Lambda^2\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n!}\log^n(\Lambda^2)= \Lambda^2 e^{-\log(\Lambda^2)} = 1.
$$
So clearly logarithmic corrections can remove certain divergences. Granted this is a convergent sum whereas in QFT we expect some kind of asymptotic series, but I would not be surprised if similar examples can be cooked up in the latter case. Is it known that the higher-loop contributions to $m_H$ do not work to make the difference $m_0-m_H$ small? Perhaps the answer is that such examples are contrived, and I would not necessarily disagree, but it would still be more satisfying to know for sure that the perturbation series did not exhibit this behavior.

My second question is more one of principle. Since $-a\Lambda^2$ is supposed to be huge, why can we trust the perturbative calculation? To my understanding perturbative calculations are usually done in the vicinity of a Gaussian (free) theory. But here, whatever it is we're expanding around, clearly the calculation takes us far away from where we started, simply because the difference between $m_0$ and $m_H$ is so large. Even if we are always close to a free theory, we have "traversed a long distance" in theory space from $\Lambda$ down to $1\text{ TeV}$ or whatever so that approximation error could have built up.

Comment: I don't know much about hierarchy problem - my conception was that such a cancellation is indeed possible, but rare generically, to the extent that it almost seems like a conspiracy. Imposing extra symmetries is one way to force this conspiratorial cancellation to occur. Your point about "corrections being large", I believe there should be couplings attached to the correction you wrote. In any case, https://arxiv.org/pdf/2205.05708.pdf seems like a nice reference, I'm reading right now and I'll write an answer if I figure anything out

Comment: Thanks for the reference, at the very least looks like a nice overview. I'm not sure what you are referring to when you say that couplings should be attached. Maybe that the RG flow mixes all of the effective lagrangian's parameters as the scale runs?

Comment: I was just comparing your equation against equation 21 in the reference I sent. Even though the one-loop correction is large due to the appearance of an extra scale Lambda, at higher loops the corrections should still be suppressed by couplings, which must be small for perturbation theory to make any sense

Comment: I see what you mean. Now, in my infinite series example, the terms fall roughly as $n!$ which is pretty fast and yet the ultimate result is still very different from $\Lambda^2$. But I suppose if I'm bothered by that in this case, I should be complaining about QFT perturbation theory in general as opposed to the hierarchy problem...